# Is there a way to make a css effect on something when opening page with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got photos and when i click on any, it get's outline until i leave the page or click on another photo. Is there a way to make the first photo go outline when i open the page?

I expect to get outline on the first photo after i open the site

**HTML**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
<li><a onclick="return false" class="target" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" title="">
                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
                        </a></li>
<li><a onclick="return false" class="target" href="https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg"  title="">
<img src="https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg">
                        </a></li>
                                </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
a.selected{
  outline: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**JS with JQuery**

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVMpGx)

Comment: Add the `selected` class to the first `<a>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the anchor tag programmatically using the following code for the very first time on the page load.

```
$('a')[0].click();
```

[Code Pen LINK](https://codepen.io/kamalsomu/pen/KOVZEw)

Comment: Why not just add it directly to the html?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('a:first').addClass('selected');

  $('a').on('click', function() {
    $('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
a.selected{
  outline: 1px solid red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li>
    <a onclick="return false" class="target" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" title="">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a onclick="return false" class="target" href="https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg" title="">
      <img src="https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You have to wrap your entire function into [document.ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler. And add some logic when your DOM is ready(first open)

```
$(function() {
    $('a:first').addClass('selected');

        $('a').on('click', function(){
    $('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add "selected" class for as u want the image..

**HTML**

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>
        <a onclick="return false" class="target selected" href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" title="">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a onclick="return false" class="target" href="https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg"  title="">
            <img src="https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/core-image-filters@2x.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It sounds nice but my code is generated in php so i used 

$('a')[0].click();

and works nice

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $($('a')[0]).addClass('selected');
})
```

I would suggest to use a class selector instead of anchor tag. Something  like

```
.image{
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        $($('.image')[0]).addClass('selected');
    })
```